# how to call an udf with multiple arguments(currying) in spark sql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do i call the below UDF with multiple arguments(currying) in a spark dataframe as below.

**read read and get a list[String]**

```
val data = sc.textFile("file.csv").flatMap(line => line.split("\n")).collect.toList
```

**register udf**

```
val getValue = udf(Udfnc.getVal(_: Int, _: String, _: String)(_: List[String]))
```

**call udf in the below df**

```
df.withColumn("value",
     getValue(df("id"),
        df("string1"),
        df("string2"))).show()
```

Here is am missing the `List[String]` argument, and I am really not sure as how should i pass on this argument .

Comment: what is panel_df? and please post sample input and expected output and full code of udf function

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, that was a type. its df and not panel_df

Comment: and what about the rest of the comments about samples?

Answer (score 5):

I can make following assumption about your requirement based on your question

a] UDF should accept parameter other than dataframe column

b] UDF should take multiple columns as parameter

Let's say you want to concat values from all column along with specified parameter. Here is how you can do it

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def uDF(strList: List[String]) = udf[String, Int, String, String]((value1: Int, value2: String, value3: String) => value1.toString + "_" + value2 + "_" + value3 + "_" + strList.mkString("_"))

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1,"r1c1","r1c2"),(2,"r2c1","r2c2"))).toDF("id","str1","str2")

scala> df.show
+---+----+----+
| id|str1|str2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|r1c1|r1c2|
|  2|r2c1|r2c2|
+---+----+----+

val dummyList = List("dummy1","dummy2")
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", uDF(dummyList)(df("id"),df("str1"),df("str2")))



   scala> result.show(2, false)
+---+----+----+-------------------------+
|id |str1|str2|new_col                  |
+---+----+----+-------------------------+
|1  |r1c1|r1c2|1_r1c1_r1c2_dummy1_dummy2|
|2  |r2c1|r2c2|2_r2c1_r2c2_dummy1_dummy2|
+---+----+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please share java equivalent

Comment: Is it possible to register currying UDF with `spark.udf.register` ?

Answer (score 1):

Defining a UDF with multiple parameters:

```
val enrichUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((jsonData: String, id: Long) => {

      val lastOccurence = jsonData.lastIndexOf('}')
      val sid = ",\"site_refresh_stats_id\":" + id+ " }]"
      val enrichedJson = jsonData.patch(lastOccurence, sid, sid.length)

      enrichedJson

    })
```

Calling the udf to an existing dataframe:

```
val enrichedDF = EXISTING_DF
  .withColumn("enriched_column",
    enrichUDF(col("jsonData")
      , col("id")))
```

An import statement is also required as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
```